# procedurally convert interval data to cross sectional data

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, panel-data

I'm working on a project where I have a database of events with a start and end time stamp.  I want to work with the data as cross section data.

The naive solution is to iterate over every quantum of time since epoch and check it against each record's interval.

There has to be a better way.

I'm language agnostic but I'm partial to python for data analysis.

What modules can help me procedurally convert this data?

Edit:

Here is some sample data:

```
+-------+------+---------+----+
| start | end  | name    | ID |
+-------+------+---------+----+
|     0 |    7 | Bill    |  1 |
|     0 |    8 | Anne    |  2 |
|     2 |   10 | Charlie |  3 |
|     9 |   14 | David   |  4 |
|     8 |   14 | Eve     |  5 |
+-------+------+---------+----+
```

I want to change this into data like:

```
time |   name | ID
0        Bill | 1
0    |   Anne | 2
1    |   Bill | 1
1    |   Anne | 2
2    |   Bill | 1
2    |   Anne | 2
3    |   Charlie | 2
```

...

This is just a sample, I plan on using unix epoch timestamps, so iterating through every second since 1970 is unfeasible.

Comment: Could you post an example of your data?

Comment: I think SO typically frowns upon library recommendation questions, so this may get closed. Anyway, pandas is certainly capable if you're looking for a python solution. Maybe edit your question to include an example.